# A value of type 'Position?' can't be returned from the method '_getLocation' because it has a return type of 'Future<Position>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been getting Error A value of type 'Position?' can't be returned from the method '_getLocation' because it has a return type of 'Future' which I need to fix?

```
Position? userLocation;

Future<Position> _getLocation() async {
    try {
      userLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    } catch (e) {
      userLocation = null;
    }
    return userLocation;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for defining a variable outside of `_getLocation()` function?

You can do this:

```dart
Future<Position> _getLocation() async {
  try {
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Error getting user location: $e');
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```dart
final Position userLocation = await _getLocation();
```